# Eclipse Clean & Build Order

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have several Eclipse projects that are interdependent, and when I do a `Project -> Clean...` for all projects and Eclipse does its rebuild, I have several projects which will not build on the first pass with the "cannot be built until its prerequisite is built" message. All projects build properly after a couple taps of `F5` with all projects selected. I have gone to `Preferences -> Workspace -> Build Order` and tweaked the Max iterations up to 200 to no avail.

I was able to get the whole thing to behave with one pass by altering the build order manually, but since the projects are configured to be interdependent in Eclipse, I feel like I shouldn't have to do that.

I am using Gradle to recreate `.project` and `.classpath` files, but I don't have to do a `Gradle -> Refresh All` to get the wonky behavior--just a Clean.

I guess the question here is: Am I doing something wrong with Gradle/Eclipse, or is this something wrong with Eclipse itself? I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1 built on Eclipse Luna.